# Two induction motors are made, one 50hz one 60hz, other specs are same. Which one is larger in size?

Tags: frequency, induction-motor

All other specs are same. Only difference is operating frequency.

Comment: Can't have the same specs. The 50 Hz motor runs slower. Typically the motors are exchangeable, if the slower speed is ok.

Answer (score 3):

Since the specs presumably include the speed, for both motors to run at the same speed, one motor must have more poles. I'll leave the rest as an exercise.

But if the other specs also include the size, then both are the same size by the terms of the question. If neither of these answers satisfy you, then yeu may need to refine the question.

Comment: Never seen a motor datasheet where the spec doesn't include the size

Answer (score 2):

As Brian Drummond alluded to, this is an ill-defined question.  For example, if you have the same number of poles and the same rated torque, then the rated power of the 50 Hz motor is going to be less than the rated power of the 60 Hz motor.  You could have a 10 pole 50 Hz motor and a 12 pole 60 Hz motor, which would give you the same synchronous speed, but then your number of poles is different and your winding is going to be different (and the length of your end turns will change and the optimum number of slots might change, etc.).

Basically all that boils down to the fact that you can't just change the frequency of an induction motor and leave everything else the same.  The air gap flux is proportional to the voltage and inversely proportional to the frequency.  If you change the frequency, you change the flux.  Because of this, high frequency motors can in general be smaller, which is one of the reasons why airplanes often have 400 Hz motors on them.

Answer (score -1):

**All things being equal** *they'll be the same size*

Assuming they run the same speed, and produce the same torque.
Perhaps the 60Hz pne has 18 pole pieces and the other has 15 and both run at around 600RPM.

The 18 pole pieces will need each need to produce less magnetic field and so they be can be smaller, but there;s more of them so it comes out equal..

Well, there outer ring of the stator can be slightly thinner on the 60Hz motor, but that;s like 1% of the size of the motor, for most practical purposes they're the same size.

**All theings being unequal** the 3600 RPM motor will be smaller than the 3000 rpm motor for the same power rating.

With motors torque is proportional to the magnetic field, and so, the current in the windings. So the faster they run the more powerful they can be at a given size.